# Disable popup window while using the measure tool in leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using a measure plugin tool in leaflet but when I try to measure between markers the pop up window interfers is there a way to fix this? I read something about oddclicks, I tried using that to no avail.

```
$(".leaflet-control-measure").click(function() {
  var oddClick = $(this).data("oddClick");
 $(this).data("oddClick", !oddClick);
 if (!oddClick) {
   map.off('click', popup);
 } else {
    map.on('click', popup);
 }
 });
```

[image]

```
   popup logic- I am reading from a database, the popup is called from python in a for loop, and rendered using the jinja2 template
 var markers= L.markerClusterGroup({
      disableClusteringAtZoom: 15,
      minZoom : 2

  });


  {% for item in markers %}


   var resortIcon = L.icon({
       iconUrl: '{{ item[3] }}',
      iconSize: [25, 25],
      popupAnchor: [0,-15]
    });

   var marker{{ item[0] }} = L.marker({{ item[5:] }}, {icon: resortIcon});
   var popup = "<table height='90'><tr><td>{{ item[1] }}</td></tr><tr><td 
 align='center'><b><i>{{ item[4] }}</b></i></td></tr><tr><td align='center'> 
   <a href='www.google.com' onmouseover='More info'><img src='../icon/contract.svg' height=30 width=30 /></a></td></tr></table>";
  marker{{ item[0] }}.bindPopup(popup);
  markers.addLayer(marker{{ item[0] }});
  map.addLayer(markers)


  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: [Which plugin, specifically](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#measurement)? Also, what does `$(this).data()` return?

Comment: @mhodges I used this plugin https://github.com/aprilandjan/leaflet.measure I think the map, I referenced that from here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232789/disable-leaflet-wms-getfeatureinfo-popup-while-using-the-measure-tool                     although I am not using a wms getfeature info as the case in that question

Comment: What does your `popup` method look like? Maybe you can put the logic in there? `if (oddClick) { open dialog }`, rather than registering and unregistering the click handler over and over?

Comment: Also, I would name your variable and your data attribute something better than `oddClick`. You should use a name like `measureActive` or something like that -- makes your code much more self-documenting.

Comment: okay.noted..thank you. I have edited the question to show what my popup method looks like. I am looping from a database

Comment: Oh, hmm.. so `popup` is a string of HTML or a DOM element? If so, that is not how `.on()` and `.off()` work. Those register/unregister event handlers, meaning they take a function as their second parameter. Their first parameter is "which event?" - in your case, the click event. In order to be able to see exactly what is going on, I'll need more of your code. Can you post the entire piece of code where you are "looping from a database"? Also, in your top event handler, is popup a global, or are you registering that click handler inside of your loop?

Comment: @mhodges thanks a lot for the correction and help, I have added more code, the popup is looped from the database to html through the jinja2 template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are wanting to prevent the popups from appearing if you are measuring. I am by no means an expert in [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), as I have never used it before, but from digging through some of the documentation, it seems like this might be your best option.

Essentially, you can bind an event handler to the `popupopen` event on each marker, and inside that handler, you can immediately close the popup if certain conditions are met (i.e. "measure mode" is enabled).

This is how it would work:

```js
var startingCoords = [40.07573, -105.401047];
var markerCoords = [
  startingCoords,
  [40.512318, -105.665104],
  [39.825169, -104.994123],
];
var map = L.map('map').setView(startingCoords, 8);
var enablePopups = document.getElementById("enablePopups");
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

function onPopupOpen(e) {
  // check if you it is okay for the popup to open - if not, close it.
  if (!enablePopups.checked) {
    // "this" refers to the marker object of the marker that was clicked on, whereas
    // e.target will refer to the DOM element itself
    this.closePopup();
  }
}

// loop to create each marker
markerCoords.forEach(function (coords) {
  var marker = L.marker(coords).addTo(map).bindPopup('Location at [' + coords + ']');
  // use .bind(marker) so we can access the marker itself via "this" inside the onPopupOpen
  // handler. That way, we don't have to keep an array of markers as a reference - each one
  // is self-referencing.
  marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen.bind(marker));
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
Enable Popups ? <input type="checkbox" checked id="enablePopups" />
<p>Click on a marker with "enable popups" checked vs unchecked - you can manually disable the popups based on a condition</p>
<div id="map"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that once we add popup to the layer/polygon, the click on it will be captured first and stops further event propagation, thus makes the measure layer cannot get the click event to draw line.

How ever, we can bypass that though some tricky methods. For example, when start measuring, loop through all layers and remove their click event handlers to prevent them from responding to click; and then, after finish measuring, we add back their click event handlers to keep its original behavior.

Here's the tricky:

```js
 //  the cached clicks for other layers
  _cachedClicks: [],

  //  try to remove click event handlers of other layers
  _removeOtherLayersClicks: function (layer) {
    if (layer === this._layerPaint) {
      return;
    }
    var loop = function (childLayer) {
      if (childLayer._events && childLayer._events.click) {
        this._cachedClicks.push({
          layer: childLayer,
          click: childLayer._events.click,
        });
        childLayer._events.click = undefined;
      }
      if (childLayer.eachLayer) {
        this._removeOtherLayersClicks(childLayer);
      }
    }.bind(this);
    layer.eachLayer(loop);
  },

  //  try to bring back the click event handlers
  _addOtherLayersClicks: function () {
    this._cachedClicks.forEach(function (cached) {
      var layer = cached.layer;
      var click = cached.click;
      layer._events.click = click;
    });
  },
```

You can check more details in https://github.com/aprilandjan/leaflet.measure/issues/8