# With leaflet in bootstrap-vue remove default dialog popup on marker's click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bootstrap-vue

In vue/ bootstrap-vue app with leaflet 1.6.0 I make custom modal dialog on marker clicking
and I can not remove default dialog popup. I do

```
            let nextMarker = this.leaflet.marker(
                [nextLocationPoint.lat, nextLocationPoint.lng], {icon: markerIcon})
                .addTo(locationsMap)
                .bindPopup(nextLocationPoint.title)
                .on('mouseover', this.locationMarkerOnMouseOver)
                .on('click', this.locationMarkerOnClick)  

    methods: {

        locationMarkerOnClick(e) {
            console.log('locationMarkerOnClick e::')
            console.log(e)

            // e.stopPropagation()  // THIS RAISE ERROR
            // e.preventDefault()  // THIS RAISE ERROR

            e.cancelBubble = true
            window.event.cancelBubble = true  // NOTHING OF THESE METHODS WORK
            window.event.preventDefault(e)
            window.event.stopPropagation()

            this.$bvModal.show('viewAdLocationModal')

            return false
        }, // locationMarkerOnClick(e) {
```

I know that in vuejs syntax like :

```
<div @click.stop.prevent.self="">
```

OR

```
@click.prevent="handleClick"
```

But if it can be used for my case with leaflet?

How to fix this issue?

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.3.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this [Disable popup window while using the measure tool in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630832/disable-popup-window-while-using-the-measure-tool-in-leaflet) link I found a decision in :

```
let nextMarker = this.leaflet.marker(
    [nextLocationPoint.lat, nextLocationPoint.lng], {icon: markerIcon})
    .addTo(locationsMap)
    .bindPopup(nextLocationPoint.title)
    .on('mouseover', this.locationMarkerOnMouseOver)
    .on('click', this.locationMarkerOnClick)
    .on('popupopen', this.locationMarkerOnPopupOpen)
```

and :

```
locationMarkerOnPopupOpen(e) {
    console.log('locationMarkerOnPopupOpen e::')
    console.log(e)
    e.sourceTarget.closePopup();
    return false
}, // locationMarkerOnPopupOpen(e) {
```

That is just what I need!